# how to give path file to show the path in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, gpx

I am creating a Android application to that stores location of device at fixed interval of time to a file. The locations make a path as the device goes from one location to other. But I want this path to be displayed in google maps.

Currently I am writing to a text file, i've seen GPX format too, should I write a GPX file, but then how to fetch this file to google maps, is there any API available ?

I am using https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll/ in this there is a demo project on which I am relying.

Files : -
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/locpoll/demo/LocationReceiver.java
and LocationPollerDemo.java which is Activity class in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Maps V2 has no built-in ability to convert any sort of file into a `Polyline` or similar route. Hence, store it in whatever will be convenient for you to create the `Polyline` yourself.

Comment: Then I should store the locations in a Polyline object then display the route on Map using Overlay, but how do I store coordinates on a object, and when logging stops how to retrieve it ?

Comment: @fz8975: "Then I should store the locations in a Polyline object" -- that is not possible. What you are presently doing ("I am writing to a text file") is perfectly fine.

Comment: ok..but how do I show the path. In browser ? or in Google Maps

Comment: How to show the path using coordinates in the file ?? Help ..!

Comment: @fz8975: Use a `Polyline` to *display* the path. Use a file or database to *save* the path.

Comment: I downloaded Google Play services for google maps api but it does not contain Polyline class...any idea what could be the problem ??

Comment: @fz8975: "I downloaded Google Play services for google maps api but it does not contain Polyline class" -- yes, it does. I use it here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Poly

Comment: ok thats solved but I have a new problem now..`LocationReceiver` writes location in `Location` class object  but in `Polyline` I can only add `Latlng`...??

Comment: @fz8975: Grab the latitude and longitude out of the `Location` object and create a `LatLng` object containing those values. Please do not comment further on this answer. If you have additional questions, use the "Ask Question" link in the upper-right corner of this page.

Comment: One Last question How do I get the current Latitude and Longtitude in the Main Activity ? I want to display it in `TextView`